# How to measure area height and width in pixels (rather than cm) in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I just started using Photoshop CS6 because i needed to make a design for an application. I wanted to use the rectanglure marquee tool to messure the height and width of an square in pixels but instead the tool is showing it in centimeters, like this:

[image]

The tool is showing the height and width in cm and i want that it show it in pixels. How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the ruler. Then right-click the ruler and select *pixels*.

Comment: The OP wants to make the measurements in pixels, not centimeters. How does this accomplish that?

Comment: That works the same way. Pixels is an option as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i will mark it as an awnser as soon as i can